# Can I have an infinite ability score if I live long enough?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, ability-scores

There are very rare magic items that increase your stat score by two, such as the Manual of Bodily Health. these items say once you use them they lose their magic until a century passes. I can't find anywhere stating that it cannot increase your score above a 20.

Is it possible that if my character has the Manual of Bodily Health and lives 1000 years, he could have a Constitution score of 40 with a +15 Con modifier and a +15 to each level in HP?